# Can ubuntu 11.10 be installed on a 1T hard drive?

Tags: installation, hard-drive

I tried to install Ubuntu 11.10 on a Gateway machine and an Acer machine. In each case, I tried the same 1T hard drive. However, after the install, neither the Gateway nor the Acer would boot up to the Ubuntu log on screen - both stopped at the terminal, with a flashing underscore. Ubuntu worked fine on the Acer with a 320G hard drive. Will Ubuntu 11.10 install on a 1T hard drive?

Comment: Is that an internal drive? Did you try to boot from Live-CD and check if the drive is accessible?

Comment: Actually, I found Ubuntu works fine on a 1T hard drive. During the installation, the boot drive was changed. When I boot from the drive with the OS, it works fine.